# “It took me all of ten minutes to find out” - what does “it took me” mean?

Tags: grammar

I have a little confusion on understanding the sentence:

> It took me all of ten minutes to find out .

Why couldn't it be "I took all of ten minutes to find out"?

Comment: Could you please add context? I can think of a few different ways to explain this depending on that

Comment: @simchona ok it took me all of ten minutes to find out my notebook. it this is correct or should I use  _I took all of ten minutes to find out my notebook_.what does _it took me_ mean?

Comment: This seems like proof reading now.

Comment: I protest the closing. I would re-open this if I knew how. There are a number of issues that could use addressing here, and now I can't post the answer I've been working on for 15 minutes. This is not the first time people have closed questions because they didn't approve of them.

Comment: @john you can always ask on Meta, or ping the mod Reg who cast the supervote on this. Personally, this comes across as proof reading--the OP doesn't have enough of a handle on English for this to be a very good question

Comment: **Most** of our posters don't have much of a handle on English, as is clear from their questions. I asked on Meta. Vamos a ver, como se dice.

Comment: @JohnLawler If people do not have a decent handle on English before coming here, this is not the place for them, IMO.

Comment: Contradictory answers are a clue that it might not be as simple a question as the closer thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is you can use both. The phrasing is flexible.

> "*It took me* ten minutes."

means the same as

> "*I took* ten minutes."

The first phrase is probably more common and sounds more natural to an English speaker, but there is nothing more *correct* about it.

Answer (score 11):

Actions consume resources. *Took* here is used to mean *consumed*:

> Filling the hole *took* 12 bags of soil.
>
> Driving to work *took* half a tank of fuel.
>
> Beating the last level of the game *took* five attempts.
>
> Finding out *took* ten minutes.

Sometimes it makes sense to specify *who* consumed those resources:

> Filling the hole took *Ted* 12 bags of soil.
>
> Driving to work took *Alice* half a tank of fuel.
>
> Beating the last level of the game took *you* five attempts.
>
> Finding out took *me* ten minutes.

Since "Filling the hole", "Driving to work" etc. are noun phrases, we can replace them with the pronoun *it*.

> *It* took Ted 12 bags of soil.
>
> *It* took Alice half a tank of fuel.
>
> *It* took you five attempts.
>
> *It* took me ten minutes.

But now that we've lost that detail, we may want to put it back in:

> It took Ted 12 bags of soil *to fill the hole*.
>
> It took Alice half a tank of fuel *to drive to work*.
>
> It took you five attempts *to beat the last level of the game*.
>
> It took me ten minutes *to find out*.

In speech, you might have already spoken "It took me ten minutes ..." before realising that you need to explain what "it" is, so you add it on afterwards. That's one reason a "backwards" form of the sentence exists.

Another reason is that it it allows you to emphasise one part over the other. The "taking ten minutes" part is the focus of the sentence, and what gets the listener's attention.

Written English mimics spoken English.

---

There is a subtle semantic difference between these two:

> David took 10 minutes to find the notebook.
>
> It took David 10 minutes to find the notebook.

In the first, David takes 10 minutes from his "supply of time", in order to find the notebook. David is *giving* his time to the activity.

In the second, the activity of finding the notebook, takes 10 minutes from "David's supply of time". The activity is *taking* time from David.

---

Although it's not the question, for completeness: "all of ten minutes" is a stock phrase meaning "ten minutes, which I consider to be a very small effort; you could have done the same".

Comment: This is an extraordinary answer! Seriously, I'm going to go dig through your old posts looking for gems like this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simple version would be "It took me ten minutes to find out"

“It took me all of ten minutes to find out” is to suggest that it took only a small amount of time. "All of" 10mins is a sarcastic way of saying that 10mins wasn't that much.

So we could say here, "it took me all of 10seconds to Google that answer"

Comment: ok that's good .but why I cann't use _I took_ all of 10 minutes to find out my notebook?

Comment: You don't "find out" a notebook. I think you need to work on phrasal verbs.

Comment: @KrishnaChandraTiwari - "it took me all of 10minutes to find my notebook", means you spent 10mins looking for it

Answer (score 0):

Sentences generally require a subject, the person or thing the sentence is about, and in your second sentence the subject is *I*, that is, the person speaking. Because the grammar of a sentence needs a subject, we sometimes have to invent one, even though it has no meaning. That is the case in your second sentence. *It* is there simply to meet the grammatical requirement, and because it is empty of meaning it is called a‘dummy *it*’. (But now see comments below.)

Comment: I don't think it's a dummy *it*. It's a pronoun standing in for "finding the notebook" (even though that's defined later in the sentence).

Comment: @slim: You're right. More a case of extraposition.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are meaningful and grammatically correct. They are also similar in meaning. The only difference between them is their sentence constructions. 
The first sentence takes the form of "**It + (conjugated form of *take*, e.g., *took***) **+ object + time taken (length/amount of time) + to-infinitive**" whereas the second takes the form of **"Subject + (*take*) + length/amount of time + to-infinitive"**, which is very simple in English grammar. Note that the subject *it* in the second form is known as ***dummy pronoun*** or ***empty subject*** or sometimes as ***impersonal subject***.

Comment: You're not wrong, but someone else already said this and much more. Your time would be better spent answering questions that don't already have good answers.